# Stripe/PHP: No such token in LIVE mode, a similar object exists while in TEST mode

Tags: php

Using PHP with stripe integration, creating charge gives me "No such token found". However, when I switch into TEST mode and change the keys, it says "A similar object exists in live mode.

I understand that this issue is usually a problem with the account being in the wrong mode, but I have verified that the card I am trying to charge too has the correct name and is not a test card.

PHP Code:

```
$charge = \Stripe\Charge::create(array(
    "amount" => 2000,
    "currency" => "usd",
    "source" => $cust,
    "description" => "LendIt Rental"
));
```

Answer (score 1):

This was solved by using the Stripe API to create a token object instead of passing in a customer ID or card ID. Using test data my code looked something like this

Creating the token:

```
$token = \Stripe\Token::create(array(
    "card" => array(
    "number" => "4242424242424242",
    "exp_month" => 10,
    "exp_year" => 2018,
    "cvc" => "314"
     )
));
```

Charging to the token

```
$charge = \Stripe\Charge::create(array(
    "amount" => 2000,
    "currency" => "usd",
    "source" => $token,
    "description" => "Charge"
));
```

This was NOT an issue with API versions but attempting to use a different method for creating charges.